# Magento XML parser error when trying to create simple widget which reads from google docs csv

Tags: php, magento, csv, xml-parsing, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a simple widget which will read from a google docs spreadsheet and print a table on my website.  So far in the Block folder I have:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_table
extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
implements Mage_widget_block_interface
{
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $spreadsheet_url= pathToCSV;

        if(!ini_set('default_socket_timeout',    15)) echo "<!-- unable to change socket timeout -->";

        if (($handle = fopen($spreadsheet_url, "r")) !== FALSE) 
        {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
            {
                $spreadsheet_data[]=$data;
                return $spredsheet_data[];
            }
        fclose($handle);
        }
        else 
            return 'Problem reading csv';
    }
}
?>
```

This is a fairly basic code just to test if it's reading from the file correctly, but whenever I upload the folder containing the extension to the server, the entire dev site just displays:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 19: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: modules line 3 and config  in /home/web/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/home/uriderdev...', 510, Array)
#1 /home/uriderdev/web/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php(510): simplexml_load_string('loadString('loadFile('/home/uriderdev...')
#4 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesConfiguration(Array, Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config))
#5 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(406): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModules()
#6 /home/uriderdev/web/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(334): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#7 /home/uriderdev/web/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#8 /home/uriderdev/web/index.php(92): Mage::run('', 'store')
#9 {main}
```

Is there something I'm obviously doing wrong?

Edit: heres my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </module>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <module>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Helper</class>
            </module>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <module>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Block</class>
            </module>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Non-wellformed XML would be my guess. A `find -type f -name '*.xml' -exec xmllint --noout {} \;` in `app/code` might be helpful.

Comment: thanks for the reply, what exactly does that do?

Comment: The `simplexml_load_string` stack trace doesn't tell you, which of the `*.xml` files failed and cuts the error output. The `xmllint` line checks whether all found `*.xml` files are well-formed and outputs file name and found errors, if not.

Comment: Your shown `config.xml` misses a closing `</modules>` tag, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP code isn't the problem here.  As part of your widget module, you've uploaded one, possibly more than one, XML file.  When Magento uses PHP code to read this XML file, (probably your `config.xml`, but that's a guess based on the call stack you listed), it finds the XML file is invalid.

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 19: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: modules line 3 and config

It sounds like some tags in your file aren't balanced correctly.  Fix this problem, and you'll be able to move on.

**Update**: Per the updated answer, the following

```
...
<modules>
    <Scooterlistwidget>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Scooterlistwidget>
<global>
...
```

should be

```
<modules>
    <Scooterlistwidget>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Scooterlistwidget>
</modules>
<global>
```

You're missing a closing `</modules>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, here's my config file, it all looks balanced to me :\  edit: looks ugly in comments, will put it in original post

Comment: @edward Always best to have a computer/editor determine the balanced-ness of your XML files. Answer updated.